# How to fetch $20.67 data from excel in android

Tags: android, excel, apache-poi, currency

I am using Apache POI to fetch the data from excel.
They have given some types to fetch the data from excel.
But they have not given any code to fetch the currency value from excel.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        cellValue = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
                    } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        cellValue = "" + currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
                    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with [DataFormatter as per the docs](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)?

Comment: String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                            System.out.println("Formatted" + text);

I am getting output as cell number eg : K110*B110 

but what i need is the value. eg : $20.98 like wise

Comment: Pass in a `FormulaEvaluator` object too - you'd neglected to mention this was a formula cell!

Comment: @Gagravarr  Your hint made me get the output . Thank you.